# How to use Kingfisher image library or AlamofireImage in watch OS 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, watchkit, alamofireimage

Watch OS doesn't have ImageView but the above two libraries are working like as ImageView extension only. They have mentioned it will support watch os 2 but can't find any related docs.

Answer (score 0):

achieved by using

`let URL = NSURL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/master/images/kingfisher-\(currentIndex! + 1).jpg")!
        KingfisherManager.sharedManager.retrieveImageWithURL(URL, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil) { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
            self.interfaceImage.setImage(image)
        }`